# How to make a dynamic JPanel stick to the top?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, gridbaglayout

I'm using GridBagLayout and JPanel 2 seems to always be in the center of the JPanel 1. JPanel 2 gets dinamically adjusted in height throughout the program, so I can't stick it to the top using `gbc.insets.top = -15;` (gbc = GridBagConstraints) for example. I've tried `gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;` or `gbc.gridheight = 3;` but they don't seem to do what I'm looking for.

**Assuming JPanel 1 and JFrame stay the same size, (JFrame isn't resizable), how can I make JPanel 2 be all the way at the top, without that gap?**

[image]

Comment: Overlayed components isn't something inherently supported by gridbaglayout. I'd suggest you try using the modal layer of the JLayeredPane, or perhaps a CardLayout on a JPanel inside your GridBagLayout

Comment: *I'm using GridBagLayout* - where? On the frame? I don't see any code where you set the layout manager or add a component to the frame. Post a proper [mre] with every question so we don't have to guess exactly what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> JPanel 2 seems to always be in the center of the JPanel

Then it would seem you are adding panel1 to panel2, since the default behaviour for the GridBagLayout is to center the component relative to its parent.

Based on the picture shown just use the `BorderLayout` on the frame (which is the default). Then you would:

1. add panel2 to the `BorderLayout.LINE_START`
2. add panel1 to the `BorderLayout.CENTER`

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) for more information.